# How to use avg and sum in SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to return a totals/averages row from my dataset which contains the SUM of certain fields and the AVG of others.

I could do this in SQL via:

```
SELECT SUM(field1) as SumFld, AVG(field2) as AvgFld 
FROM Rating WHERE url=[url_string]
```

My attempt to translate this into SQLAlchemy is as follows:

```
totals = Rating.query(func.avg(Rating.field2)).filter(Rating.url==url_string.netloc)
```

But this is erroring out with:

```
TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You should use something like:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
session.query(func.avg(Rating.field2).label('average')).filter(Rating.url==url_string.netloc)
```

You cannot use `MyObject.query` here, because SqlAlchemy tries to find a field to put result of `avg` function to, and it fails.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling it should be using `session` but wasn't understanding why. Now I get it, thanks for the help, it's working well now.

Comment: I think it would be good to mention, you have to import

`from sqlalchemy.sql import func`

Comment: How  session.query understood that it has to run this query in Rating Table ?

Comment: @ted: ``Rating`` is defined in the above example in two places: 1) within ``func.avg()`` and 2) in ``filter()``

Answer (score 56):

> You cannot use MyObject.query here, because SqlAlchemy tries to find a field to put result of avg function to, and it fails.

This isn't exactly true. `func.avg(Rating.field2).label('average')` returns a `Column` object (the same type object that it was given to be precise). So you can use it with the `with_entities` method of the query object.

This is how you would do it for your example:

```
Rating.query.with_entities(func.avg(Rating.field2).label('average')).filter(Rating.url == url_string.netloc)
```

Comment: this is the correct answer because will the flask-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 2):

```
attention = Attention_scores.query
    .with_entities(func.avg(Attention_scores.score))
    .filter(classroom_number == classroom_number)
    .all()
```

I tried it like this and it gave the correct average.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the correct format, also, please describe why does your answer works? and what was wrong?. Please take a look at our guidelines on [how do I format my post?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the existing decade-old answers